# Show all images from folder

Tags: php

am trying to display all images from a folder, but it is only showing JPEG images not png , please help me

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $nameof = $_POST['searchid'];
            $dirname = $nameof."/";


            $files = glob( $dirname."*.*");

            for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)

            {

            $image = $files[$i];


            echo '<img width="250" class="all-seletc-wrap" src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try doing `print_r($files);`? Does it contain all the files you need?

Comment: my folder contains all type of images png and jpeg also, but it showing me just jpeg images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` loop use `foreach` loop as latter will iterate through all files.

```
<?php
foreach (glob($dirname."*.*") as $image) {
echo '<img width="250" class="all-seletc-wrap" src="'.$image .'" 
      alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: yes you did..i can see that..:)

Comment: @Joke_Sense10: Could you explain why the `for` wouldn't suit the OP's needs? It will also iterate through all the items (minus one).

Answer (score 0):

What about use directory Iterator?.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nameof = $_POST['searchid'];
    $dirname = $nameof."/";

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dirname) as $file) {
      if($file->isDot()) continue;

      $required = array("jpg", "png");

      if(in_array($file->getExtension(), $required)) {

        $fileName = $file->getFilename();
        $image = $file->getPath() . $fileName;

        echo '<img width="250" class="all-seletc-wrap" src="'.$image .'" alt="Random     image" />'."<br /><br />";
      }
    }
}
```